# Webrtc and citrxi vdi plugin

Tags: plugins, webrtc, citrix, vdi

If we use webrtc in citrix hosted enviroment, then as a thin client running webtrc app in a browser, do we will really a VDI plugin to have audio/video for point to point streaming from the local machine to the other end and avoid streaming through server.

Or webrtc running at the local thin client is already providing a point to point streaming through local client and avoiding the citrix server.

Please let me know your comments and also if there is a way other than I mentioned where webrtc will require a vdi plugin for point to point streaming and really avoid server for the media streaming.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I research this few years ago when we implemented Cisco Jabber Softphone Audio + Video in Citrix environment. You need a VDI plugin otherwise Media termination will happen in remote Data Center. Cisco call it VMXE to perform Local voice & video processing:

http://d2zmdbbm9feqrf.cloudfront.net/2015/usa/pdf/BRKCRS-2200.pdf

[image]

With Webrtc the browser candidates will announce the available IP addreses (via ICE, stun and TURN) for the machine running the web browser, in this case won't be the client, you need a broker which allows this termination locally.

Comment: Thanks for a response !

Comment: Thanks for a response ! My question is if user1 in your above diagram has webrtc based HTML5 browser. By this i mean Thin client has HTMl5 based browser which supports webrtc. Then do we really need to have hosted apps in citrix virtual environment. Will thin client provide all the required stacks to have a call directly with the other users by passing the virtual environment. My ask really is with webrtc coming up does vdi plugin will have any place in the future to provide direct media ?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2016/04/28/refreshing-user-experience-with-receiver-for-chrome-2-0/ I havent look the details but looks promising of what you are trying to achieve.